# Multi column combo box's Not In List Event causes move to next record when adding new entry

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combo box with 4 columns (ID, Municipality, Rayon (= County), Oblast (= Province)). The data source comes from 3 linked tables (Municipality, Rayon, Oblast). When I get a NotInList Event and add the new Municipality Name and the Rayon ID to the Municipality table, the next record is selected (the focus moves to the next record) for no apparent reason. If I select an existing entry from the combo box, the current record stays as expected.

My code works if I am only using the standard 2-column setup. If I combine Municipality, Rayon and Oblast into one entry and therefore have a 2 column list, I get the same problem. I have tried different approaches for handling the event that I found on the Web, but the problem remains. It is obvious that this has to do with the multicolumn setup, but I am still looking for a workaround.

AddMunicipality is called from several different forms from the NotInList Event. AddMunicipalityQuestion gets a valid Rayon ID.

```
Public Sub AddMunicipality(newData As String, Response As Integer)
    Dim newRayon As Integer
    Dim newOblast As Integer

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    If AddMunicipalityQuestion(newData, newRayon) Then
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Municipalities (MunName, Rayon) VALUES (""" & newData & """, " & newRayon & ");"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a Municipality from the list.", _
        vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Unknown Municipality"
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    End If

Exit_Procedure:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
      MsgBox Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description, vbInformation, "AddMunicipality()"
    Resume Exit_Procedure
End Sub
```

The new municipality is added correctly, but for some reason the next record (or a new record) is getting the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grabbing the row id after the insertion, then filtering on that manually? E.g. using the query for the multicolumn, and assuming the RayonID is a bound field in the combo box:

```
dim newItemNum as long
newItemNum = dlookup("RayonID","MulticolumnQuery","MunName='" & MunName & "'")
Me.combobox.Value =  newItemNum
```

Comment: The comboBox value is set correctly. After the end of the NotInList event procedure the selection moves forward by 1 record. The value in the originally selected record is saved correctly. If I select that record, everything is as expected.  I just do not know or understand why the selected record changes and how I could prevent the change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: It had nothing to do with the multicolumn combo box after all. Although it was the first field on the form, it was the last tab stop and the forms Cycle property was set to "All Records". I entered new records by pressing tab, old ones I selected from the menu.
Sorry to all those that wasted a thought on this non-problem.